# How to use left and inner joins on two different tables in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have table1 'leads' and I want to use two  joins left as well as inner applying on two different tables such as 'lead_status' and 'assigned_leads'. I am very much new to cakephp 3.x concept hence could not understand how to write query using multiple joins.  Please suggest me how to write that query. Thanks in advance.

this is my association made in leads Table Model:

```
class LeadsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
$this->hasMany('LeadStatus', [
            'className' => 'LeadStatus',
            'foreignKey' => 'lead_id',
            'propertyName' => 'LeadStatus'
        ]);

         $this->hasMany('AssignedLeads', [
            'className' => 'AssignedLeads',
            'foreignKey' => 'lead_id',
            'propertyName' => 'AssignedLeads'
        ]);
}
}
```

I am using cake php 3.x.  Please suggest how to write multiple joins.

I have tried like this but not giving proper conditionally data

```
$query = $table->find('all')->leftJoinWith('LeadStatus')->innerJoinWith('AssignedLeads')->contain(['LeadStatus' => function($q) {
                    return $q->contain(['LeadBuckets', 'LeadBucketSubStatus'])
                                    ->where(['LeadStatus.is_active' => 1]);
                }],['AssignedLeads' => function($s) {
                    return $s->contain(['Users'])
                                    ->where(['AssignedLeads.is_active' => 1]);
                }])->where(['Leads.sub_agent_id' => $subAgentId,

            ]);
```

Comment: How do you confirm if this is not working ? Will you post what output you expect and what result  you are getting.

Comment: Actually , there is a column 'id' which is primary key of table lead , and this id is accociated with same column name i.e. 'lead_id' in both tables such as 'assigned_leads' and 'lead_status' and hence I want only data present in all three tables otherwise no data. My query is showing data but conditions of 'assigned_leads' is not working properly. that is the problem.

Comment: well, please post the result of that query.